# How can I make the jQuery 'show' function use 'display: inline-block'

Tags: jquery, ajax, show

I have an AJAX loader on my page. It's hidden using CSS `display: none;` to start with, and then shown during the AJAX routine -

```
t.ajax_loader.show('explode', {}, 1000);
```

I use 'explode' because the loader isn't that big (due to where I have to put it), and I want to help make it more obvious that it's there.

However, using the above jQuery changes the `disply` type of the loader to `inline` by default. This is no good to me, as I require `inline-block`.

The [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/show/) suggest a few options are available, but none of this seem related to this. Does anybody know of a way i can do this? Thanks.

**Update**

As per the suggestion by @PatsyIssa, I'm trying to implement the `animate` function.

Here is what I've tried, however the `display` property seems to get ignored. Also, I'm not sure how I could use the explode effect in conjuction with this? Thanks.

```
t.ajax_loader.animate({
    display: 'inline-block'
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You could make it into a custom animation

Comment: I was unaware I could do that. Presumably the `explode` effect is set up using a similar method, thus I could copy it and amend as required?

Answer (score 0):

Use `opacity` or `visibility` options.

Answer (score 0):

After the show animation is complete, use:

```
$('#myElementId').css('display', 'inline-block');
```

Comment: Won't it make it bounce? Or is it too fast to be noticed

Comment: I thought of that, but if I do that the animation is not showing correctly, as an `inline` element ignores the `width` property (thus it's only as wide as the `&nbsp;` character). Thanks.